# Updating div that has dynamic content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have a div which displays messages sent by users, when a user clicks on the 'save_convo' button the div content is translated as a JS variable called 'story', passed along a querystring and shown on a different page.

**JS**

```
    var element = document.getElementById('msg_display');
    var story = element.textContent || element.innerText; 
 // Getting text content as we only want to display the messages

$( document ).ready(function() { // button that triggers passing of data
$('#save_convo').click(function() {
    window.location.href = 'http://ex.com/publish.php?convo=' + story + '';
    return false;
});
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="msg_display">
<!-- messages are shown here -->
</div>
```

The problem is that because the div content is originally empty(on page load there are no messages), when a user clicks the button, they are taken to a blank page which doesn't show any of the messages sent by the users. How do I update the div after a message is sent to it? I've also considered reloading the div w/ AJAX but I reckon it will only refresh the div and get rid of the messages rather than retain them.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I don't get it, what messages, from where? Are you sure you're not looking for something more like Websockets ?

Comment: It is a websocket app, the users type into the chat input, click send, and the message is displayed in the msg_display div. I just want to pass the data from the div into another page.

Comment: Pretty trough problem, I'd suggest AJAX but as you said, it would only clear all current data in the div. It would be better if your data was put into a textarea as it's easy to update values from there but I assume there's a good reason you've chose divs instead.

Answer (score 0):

Use `document.getElementById('msg-display').innerHTML` instead of `.innerText` and `textContent`.

Comment: Already tried, doesn't work. The problem is that the div does not update it's value accordingly to the new messages sent